# Application server hangs up the Queue when multiple docs are uploaded

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, architecture, load-balancing, web-garden

This question is about the structure I want to create for a application.
I have developed an application for document viewer.

```
* Application is hosted in IIS Server. 
* Doc Conversion .EXE is hosted in 1st APPLICATION SERVER.
* Doc Repair .EXE is hosted in 2nd APPLICATION SERVER.
```

The flow is like, when user uploads multiple documents, the uploaded documents are given to a APPLICATION SERVER to convert it from any format to Image format.

Then user will see docs on grid, and can click on them to view.
Now in view mode, if documents are not converted properly, then on viewer there is option to "repair". By clicking this, the document will be given to another APPLICATION SERVER to repair documents.

If user click on doc, then that doc will be given to 2nd APPLICATION SERVER to repair it.

Now problem is, if user clicks on more then 2 or 3 documents with 100's of pages, it will queue all 3 and will be stuck on later documents until it repairs the 1st one.

So my question is, how do I manage that repair request for multiple documents with 100's or 1000's of pages?

Do I need to add app servers or any thing else?

Comment: You need to make your repair application multithreaded. One thread to receive repair requests and as many threads as necessary for the documents being repaired.

Comment: each time when a user clicks on document, document will be given to exe one by one, and at that time it takes much more time to convert for many pages and later docs get stuck untill it complates the 1st document.